# Opening a new window with a button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, new-window

I need to open a new window for my printing can any one let me know how to do this?

**My button Click code:**

My window.location works, but cant use the window.open

```
$('.btnFromIndexPrint').click(function () {
    if (document.URL.indexOf('index') > -1) {
         // window.location = '../Print/' + $(this).attr('id');
         window.open = '../Print/' + $(this).attr('id');
    } else {
        //window.location = 'Contract/Print/' + $(this).attr('id'); //Redirect  from Index page to print action
        window.open = 'Contract/Print/' + $(this).attr('id');
    }

});
```

**My html:**

I know there is something called target ="blank" id don't think it will work though.

```
<input type="button" value="Print" class="btnFromIndexPrint" id="@item.SalesContractId"/>
```

---

**How would i open a redirect on a new page?**

***Important!!!!!!!***

```
return RedirectToAction("Print", new { id = contractInstance.SalesContractId });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should be:

```
window.open(url_or_your_page);
```

See: [Example](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: Thanks this worked:   window.open('Contract/Print/' + $(this).attr('id'));

Comment: You can mark it as Accepted answer if that suited your need... :)

Comment: I will, you can only click the tick after 10 min tho :) could you check out the new small question at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Plz check out the new small question at the bottom... any ideas?

Comment: haha grab the green tick and run :p, hey don't you have any idea how i could get that redirectToaction displaying on a new page?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for `window.location` is

```
window.location = "url";
```

For example:

```
window.location ="http://www.mozilla.org";
```

thus it is working fine in your code.

But the syntax for `window.open()` is

```
window.open(URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])
```

For example :

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow","status=1");
```

There problem was in your syntax.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
window.open(url, [window name], "height=x,width=y");
```

When  width/height are specified , it opens it in a new window.See [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) .

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I hope you have included the above code in jQuery's document.ready function or placed the code at the bottom of the page. This is because if the specified print button has not been loaded in the DOM, the selector ($) will not find it and as such your click listener will not be attached to it.

Secondly, window.open is a function and should NOT be assigned to like a variable (which you have done above). In other words it is

```
window.open( parameters ); //NOT window.open = value;
```

See my example code below which is more or less a correction and optimisation of yours above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Window.Open</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //@Author: Prof. No Time
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.btnFromIndexPrint').click(function () {
         var urlToOpen = '';
         var docURL = document.URL;

         if (docURL.indexOf('index') > -1) {
            urlToOpen = '../Print/' + $(this).attr('id');
         }
         else {
            urlToOpen = 'Contract/Print/' + $(this).attr('id');
         }

         //alert('urlToOpen > ' + urlToOpen);
         if (urlToOpen != '') window.open(urlToOpen);
      });
   });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <input type="button" value="Print" class="btnFromIndexPrint" id="@item.SalesContractId"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I will advise against the use of such kind of IDs as shown above (@item.SalesContractId). I want to believe that somewhere that value was supposed to be substituted by the server side processing?

Hope this helps.

Comment: With regards to the new small question at the bottom of the main question. I will like a bit more explaining. window.open() already opens the link in a new window/tab. Please add more details or ask a fresh question and point me to the link.